# Options are not hiding in Safari Broswer

Tags: javascript, wordpress, safari, gravity-forms-plugin

I have Gravity form on the website, there are two option select and based on first selection, the second options are shown(I have achieved this using javascript). It is working perfectly on chrome,Firefox but it is not working on SAFARI.

The used Javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// 5: book suits form
if ($('#input_5_4').length > 0) {

    var store_lists_book_suits;
    $('#input_5_4').on('change', function () {
            current_state = $(this).val();
            output = '';

            state_string = '(' + current_state + ')';
            console.log(state_string);
            $("#input_5_5").val($("#input_5_5 option:first").val());
            $.each($('#input_5_5 option'), function (idx, val) {
                // assume state is in option format of ([state])
                idx_of_state = $(val).val().indexOf(state_string);
                if (idx == 0 || idx_of_state > 0) {
                    $(val).show();
                } else {
                    $(val).hide();
                }
            });
        });

    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
        data:{action: 'state_list_book_suits'},
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#catvalue').html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-1x" style="color:#000;text-align:center;"></i>');
        },
                dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log (data);
                store_lists = JSON.parse(data);
                //console.log(store_lists.men);
                //store_lists_women = JSON.parse(data).women;
                output = '<option>-- Please select --</option>';
                $.each(store_lists, function (index, value) {
                    output += '<option style="display:none" value="' + value.state_name + '" data-email="' + value.state_email + '">' + value.state_name + '</option>';
                });
                $('#input_5_5').html(output);

            }
        });




        $('#input_5_5').on('change', function () {
            selected_email = $('#input_5_5 option:selected').data('email');
            $('#input_5_18').val(selected_email);
        });


    // Couldn't do in Gravity Form, so do it here instead.
    $('#input_5_7').attr('type', 'number');
    $('#input_5_7').attr('min', 3);

    $('#field_5_7 .instruction').html('Minimum 3 suits');


    // This function is to prevent Chrome frontend validation. It stop working actual submit function of the form
    $('#gform_submit_button_5').on('click', function(){
        $('#gform_5').submit();
    });
}
});
```

Comment: What version of safari? Do you get an error?

Comment: It don't hide based when first option is selected.It shows all the possible options there is.All versions of safari. I am using 5.1.7 as a test site.

Comment: I don't understand how I am getting negative reputation, at least tell me the reason?

Comment: There is no error in console. The form is part of a plugin, so I have not added HTML but i can strip it off from Web inspector. After searching through internet, there had been couple of articles saying that inline css does not work in option in js for SAFARI but i am not sure how true is that. Thank you for pointing the downvote, I am new so I don't understand most of this.

Comment: The safari you mention (5.1.7) is **very** old. Maybe that's your problem. What version of jQuery are you using? I recommend using a 1.xx.xx (since this is the version that better handles older browsers). The best option would be to test in a more recent version of safari, one that people will probably use.

Comment: Also, a tip: when you answer questions made in the comments, like you did, it is good to also append that information to the question itself, so newcomers may understand you question completely more easily. Cheers.